# Can we specify the web browser with a window.open (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, window.open

My application runs with Internet Explorer and I use a `window.open` (Javascript). 
Is it possible to open this new window with Firefox?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Your website can't have any expectation of any other browser existing than the one it's currently in. Having said that, specifically for IE, there may be some ActiveX stuff.

Comment: No, that is not possible without having the user install some special browser plugin. (I don't know of any such plugin or add-on.)

Comment: Nope.  The in-browser code has no knowledge of the rest of the system outside of the browser hosting it.  All it can do is ask that browser to do things, like open a window.  That browser will then do that.